# Error when creating a delegate from a MethodInfo

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I got a suggestion on another question, to replace this piece of code:

```
string ent = c.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetGetMethod().Invoke(c, null).ToString();
```

with a delegate that can do the same thing (but which should be much faster in terms of performance).

This is what i came up so far:

```
TestClass test = new TestClass (){DummyProp= "appo"};
string prop = "DummyProp";
MethodInfo method = typeof(TestClass ).GetProperty(prop).GetGetMethod();

Func<TestClass , string> getter= (Func<TestClass , string>)
   Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TestClass , string>), test, method);
Console.WriteLine(getter(test));
```

What i am trying to do is to get at run time, the value of a property in an instance of `TestClass`, with the property that can be one of many inside of it, and which one is needed is decided by some condition

problem is that i get the following exception "the target method cannot be bound to since its signature or security transparency is not compatible with the delegate type". What am i missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```cs
Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TestClass, string>), test, method);
```

You're trying to create an open delegate, i.e. one that isn't bound to any specific instance - but you're passing the instance in. If you change that to:

```cs
Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TestClass, string>), method);
```

then it will create an appropriate open delegate.

Comment: ok that solved. I never really played with delegates, so i didn't understood that part in your blog. Thanks